# Control Volume of app

Tags: android, audio

I am developing an app which needs simple volumes control, I want **medium volume of speaker when app start after** that user can change the volume by pressing hardware key up and down(Without changing the system volume of android os)
I used below code, its working fine but once this code execute user are not able to set vibrate mode and silent mode, even app closed.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext   
 ().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    boolean isHeadSeton=audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();
    audioManager.setMode(isHeadSeton?AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION:AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);//set half volume of speaker
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 3, 0);//set half volume of call

    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(!isHeadSeton);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Please Help me..

Comment: `audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);` <-- The first argument to `setStreamVolume` should be a stream type, not an audio mode.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for your reply,can you explain little bit more or provide a sample code.